# CSVPrinter not printing to Zip

Tags: java, io, export-to-csv, zip, bufferedwriter

I have a method where I save all data by packing together images and annotations in csv format associated with them. I use CSVPrinter to print to the CSV which I'm trying to append to the zip file, but the CSV file ends up being empty. I already checked that the records I'm passing are accessible and have values

```java
public static void myCoolMethod(ArrayList<ImageDataObject> imgs, String path) throws IOException {
        File zipFile = new File(path);
        boolean result = zipFile.createNewFile();
        
        if(!result)
            return;
        
        String[] pointheader = new String[]{"x", "y", "class"};
        
        if(!result)
            return;
        
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
        
        try (ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(bos)){
            for (ImageDataObject img : imgs) {
                String imgName = img.getImageName();
                File f = new File(img.getImgPath());
                
                if(!f.exists())
                    continue;
                
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(imgName));
                Files.copy(f.toPath(), out);
                out.closeEntry();
                
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(imgName + ".csv"));
                CSVPrinter writer = new CSVPrinter(new OutputStreamWriter(out), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(pointheader));
                
                for (PcdPoint pcdPoint : img.getPointList()) {
                    writer.printRecord(pcdPoint.x, pcdPoint.y, pcdPoint.getType());
                }
                
                out.closeEntry();
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw e;
        }

        bos.close();
}
```

For additional information - pcdPoint extends Point, and x and y are public int members of the class, and getType() returns an integer as well, all primitives.

Comment: You forgot to close `writer`. In fact, don't call close(), just put _every_ closeable in a try-with-resources block.

Comment: Fair point!... But there also a simpler solution I just found by inspecting the documentation again, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 2):

The `CSVPrinter` stream in the code above uses the `OutputStreamWriter`, so it accumulated written bytes until it is closed. You need to close `CSVPrinter` in order for the contents to be written.

Alternatively, you can use `PrintStream` instead of `OutputStreamWriter`, since it prints the contents into the CSV file immediately, but it doesn't throw `IOException` so it's important to check for errors using its method `checkError()`.

Otherwise, you can use any `OutputStream` to wrap the `ZipOutputStream` that implements the `Appendable` interface, even your own.